# I keep getting an error in in MySQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server version: 5.5.23-55
- Protocol version: 10
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- cpsrvd 11.32.4.13
- MySQL client version: 5.5.23

Hi,
I keep getting MySql errors. Here is the error:

```
Error

SQL query:

# LedAds 2.x SQL Def file
# http://www.ledscripts.com/
# Do NOT try to dump this straight in
# If you must do dump this in yourself, then replace all of the
# {prefix} with whatever prefix you decided on when configuring everything
# Host: localhost
# Generation Time: Feb 11, 2002 at 08:32 PM
# Server version: 3.23.42
# Database : `pla`
# --------------------------------------------------------
#
# Table structure for table `pla_ads`
#
 CREATETABLE {prefix}_ads(

aid int( 10)unsigned NOTNULLAUTO_INCREMENT ,
 TYPE enum('image','rich')NOTNULL default'image',
did int( 10)unsigned NOTNULL default'0',
active enum('yes','no')NOTNULL default'yes',
datetime datetime NOTNULL default'0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARYKEY ( aid ) 
) TYPE=MYISAM ;



MySQL said: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{prefix}_ads (
   aid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
   type enum('im' at line 18
```

Here is my code:

```
#

CREATE TABLE {prefix}_ads (
  aid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  type enum('image','rich') NOT NULL default 'image',
  did int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  active enum('yes','no') NOT NULL default 'yes',
  datetime datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (aid)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
# --------------------------------------------------------

#
# Table structure for table `pla_images`
#

CREATE TABLE {prefix}_images (
  did int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  image_url varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  url varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  alt_text varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  target varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  width int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  height int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (did)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
# --------------------------------------------------------

#
# Table structure for table `pla_impressions`
#

CREATE TABLE {prefix}_impressions (
  aid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  impdate date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  displays bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  clicks int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (aid,impdate)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
# --------------------------------------------------------

#
# Table structure for table `pla_richtext`
#

CREATE TABLE {prefix}_richtext (
  did int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  data mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (did)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

I did change TYPE to ENGINE but still saw errors...

Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to execute these queries as it is, means is {prefix} is ever replaced with actual prefix ? I assume that you might at some stage want to replace it with actual prefix.

Comment: The answer is in the comment section at the top of the script.

Comment: # If you must do dump this in yourself, then replace all of the
# {prefix} with whatever prefix you decided on when configuring everything

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12771239#12771239

Answer (score 1):

This SQL script should be runned by a PHP script that changes the `{prefix}` to a valid prefix name

In short: `{prefix}` is not valid, it should be your prefix without the `{}`

Comment: thanks! now i got another issues: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/mu/public_html/ledads/common.inc.php(168) : runtime-created function on line 2

Comment: that's another thing. another issue, another question. Consider accepting one of the answer if they solved this problem and ask another question

Comment: i wish i knew how to accept. how?

Answer (score 1):

> # Do NOT try to dump this straight in
>
> # If you must do dump this in yourself, then replace all of the
>
> # {prefix} with whatever prefix you decided on when configuring everything

Comment: Thanks its working.. now i have another issue:

Answer (score 0):

Your {prefix} isn't defined, hence MySQL doesn't know what the value of that is -> creates error.

For testing purposes, replace all entries of "{prefix}" with "my_prefix" and you should be good to go.

Comment: got it workking now.. it would help if i read.. :(